# Query items from a database between dates

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm using PHP and SQL to create a stats summary based on weekly periods.

I initially thought all the items would have the same date and the code below worked in that situation.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2012-06-6' ORDER BY wtcode ");
```

However now I've found out that the items I need to query have varying days.

How can I change my query to get dates between 2012-06-6 and 2012-06-12 instead of only dates exactly on 2012-06-6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SQL BETWEEN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND (saledate BETWEEN '2012-06-6' AND '2012-06-12') ORDER BY wtcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
saledate between '2012-06-6' and '2012-06-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate > '2012-06-6' AND saledate < '2012-06-12' ORDER BY wtcode ");
```